# Spring and acgi security is issue with load balancing in tomcat

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, spring-security, load-balancing

i have **spring** application using **acgi security** for authentication i have also used many **filters and interceptors**, it works fine on single host machine. now i want to run my application in clustered using tomcat and also using **load balancing** of apache server. 
now when i am running my application in clustering it works fine when **used stickySession mode**,
but when i **use multicasting**, it does not allow login and always redirect to login page.

i am not guessing why this problem is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security's Security Context is stored as a value inside your session. So if your session is replicated across node then context will be available too, if you are using stick session then request will be hitting same context so it works. multicasting is not instantaneous and could be one of the reason not working in multicast mode.

i am not sure this will work or not but you can use session persistence in database and share across nodes, this will have advantage over session replication, how ever i think stick session would be best choice in my opinion.

1) http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/07/21/tomcat-6-session-persistence-through-jdbcstore/
2) [tomcat doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html)